# Using touch events instead of mouse events on Safari, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: ipad, emulation, mouseevent, touch-event

Is there a way/addon/extension that simulates the mobile events (touchstart, touchmove, touchend) instead of the normal mouseevents when navigating with Safari, Firefox or Chrome?

I'm trying to test some websites on iPad. If there is a iPad Emulator desktop software, would be great also, but I need some kind of Firebuging.

Thanks!
CaioToOn!

Answer (score 1):

You realize there is in fact an iPad simulator, which you get when you install Xcode? (Which is free, sign up at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).)

Comment: Hi, friend! You're right! http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html. Unfurtunatly, seens like a Mac only soft, do you now any for Windows? Is there any open or third party initiative? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try Phantom Limb 
http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html

Comment: Hi, Telesma. 

Very good one! Really usefull for tests on the basics events, just had to add the bookmarklet and was good to go.

The problem is that I'd like a more comprehensive test. With different user-agent and all. If possible, even with the specifics javascript engine of each mobile browser.

But this one is a good piece.

CaioToOn!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [tom robinson's virtual light table](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2008/07/11/multitouch-javascript-virtual-light-table-on-iphone-v20/). It includes a small but working mobile events emulator in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, bro. Gonna take a look and post back.

Comment: I just read it, not what I'm looking. I'm looking for a way to browse websites simulating the iPad/iPhone interactivity, not only making my scripts work as mobile. Anyway, good solution for some testing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can test touch input directly in your browser.
In Firefox or Chrome press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, which gives you a mobile view of your webpage. There you can also check if the scaling is correct.

There is a button, that lets you simulate touch events instead of mouse events.

For further information look at the [chrome device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/).